# How scipy.ndimage.median_filter works for even sizes

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, ndimage

Has someone found/understood how works `scipy.ndimage.median_filter` for even sizes?
Because I tested a lot of theories and tried to read the source code, but I haven't an explanation

(Of course it's better to use odd sizes to avoid shifts, but it's just interesting how exactly median_filter counts it for even numbers...)

Problem definition:

```
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]])
print('Size 3:')
print(median_filter(arr, size=3, cval=0, mode='constant'))
print('Size 2:')
print(median_filter(arr, size=2, cval=0, mode='constant'))
#with cval=0, mode='constant' we set that input array is extended with zeros 
#when window overlaps edges, just for visibility and ease of calculation
```

Output

```
Size 3
[[0. 2. 0.]
 [2. 5. 3.]
 [0. 5. 0.]]
Size 2
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [1. 4. 5.]
 [4. 7. 8.]]
```

As we can see for `size 3` all values are like expected, but values for `size 2` are not obvious.
If suppose that window has shape (2, 2) let's, for example, define and count all possible windows and medians for array element "9". We can cover "9" (or any other value from array) with window of shape (2, 2) in 4 different variants as shown below,

[image]

And corresponding median values would be: for red rectangle - 3, yellow - 7, green - 0, blue - 4... But the output value is 8. Even if imagine that afterwards some additional operations are applied to these medians (mean, median etc.), these operation are not obvious.

Interesting fact #1 
It seems that for 1d median_filter just takes `size-1` (so, odd) number. Example:

```
arr = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
print('1 - ', median_filter(arr, size=1, cval=0, mode='constant'))
print('2 - ', median_filter(arr, size=2, cval=0, mode='constant'))
print('3 - ', median_filter(arr, size=3, cval=0, mode='constant'))
print('4 - ', median_filter(arr, size=4, cval=0, mode='constant'))
print('5 - ', median_filter(arr, size=5, cval=0, mode='constant'))
print('6 - ', median_filter(arr, size=6, cval=0, mode='constant'))
```

Output

```
1 - [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
2 - [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
3 - [1. 2. 3. 4. 4.]
4 - [1. 2. 3. 4. 4.]
5 - [1. 2. 3. 3. 3.]
6 - [1. 2. 3. 3. 3.]
```

Interesting fact #2 
In general median_filter with even numbers works quite well, blurs images, it's even hard to determine some difference or shifts

Comment: I skimmed over the source code of the median filter as provided a thttps://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.1/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L1351-L1396. I could not find where the filter checks for whether `size` is odd or even. My guess is that the software uses code like `top_left_corner = (origin-size//2,origin-size//2)`, so in the case where size is even, it would be the yellow box. Still, I have no idea why you are getting 8. Can you post your code for the 2D case?

Comment: Hi, the code is in "Problem definition" :)
Duplicate: 
```from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]])
print('Size 3:')
print(median_filter(arr, size=3, cval=0, mode='constant'))
print('Size 2:')
print(median_filter(arr, size=2, cval=0, mode='constant'))
#with cval=0, mode='constant' we set that input array is extended with zeros 
#when window overlaps edges, just for visibility and ease of calculation```

Comment: I read over the source code again and found an answer. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Michael Sohnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5166365/michael-sohnen) answer now I understand how it works!

I'll describe the calculation process step by step for the example in "Problem definition" for `size=2` in my question

Due to the source code https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4cf21e753cf937d1c6c2d2a0e372fbc1dbbeea81/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L1244-L1307

1. At first, `footprint` is calculated from `size`. In our case `size=2`, so footprint will be an array with shape (2, 2) filled with `True` (Lines 1252-1258)
2. Then, `filter_size` is calculated  (Line 1267)

   ```
   filter_size = numpy.where(footprint, 1, 0).sum()
   ```

   `numpy.where(footprint, 1, 0)` returns 1 if an array element is True and 0 if
   False, all footprint elements are True, it means **filter_size is equal to 4**
3. `rank` is calculated (Lines 1268-1279)

   ```
   if operation == 'median':   <---- our case
     rank = filter_size // 2
   ```

   it means in our case **rank is equal to 2**
4. finding of the appropriate condition (Lines 1280-1307)

   ```
     if rank < 0:                            #<---- not our case
         rank += filter_size
     if rank < 0 or rank >= filter_size:     #<---- not our case
         raise RuntimeError('rank not within filter footprint size')
     if rank == 0:                           #<---- not our case
         return minimum_filter(input, None, footprint, output, mode, cval,
                       origins)
     elif rank == filter_size - 1:           #<---- not our case
         return maximum_filter(input, None, footprint, output, mode, cval,
                       origins)
     else:                                   #<---- our case!
         ...
         _nd_image.rank_filter(input, rank, footprint, output, mode, cval,
                       origins)
         ...
   ```

   So, `rank_filter` will be applied to the array. How works the rank filter? 
   It sorts values in the given window and then takes an element with `rank`-index
   from this sorted array.
   For example, rank=2 and window is

   ```
   4 3 
   2 1
   ```

   Sorted window is [1, 2, 3, 4] and the element on the second index
   (*starting from zero*) is 3.

   Special cases of rank filter are minimal filter (in this case
   rank=0), maximal filter (rank=length_of_an_array) and median filter
5. And finally, applying of the rank filter to the original array 
   [image]

   Blue window for element "1", sorted [0 0 0 1], the second element of the sorted array - 0 
   Red window for element "2", sorted [0 0 1 2], the second element of the sorted array - 1 
   Green window for element "3", sorted [0 0 2 3], the second element of the sorted array - 2 
   And so on... So, the first raw of the output array [0, 1, 2]

Now answers match the output!

Answer (score 1):

In scipy.ndimage.median_filter, a special case occurs when size = 2. Take a look at the source code at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.1/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L1351-L1396

The median filter calls the function `_rank_filter`, which you can find here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4cf21e753cf937d1c6c2d2a0e372fbc1dbbeea81/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L1244

In the function, you'll find the code:

```
if rank < 0:
    rank += filter_size
if rank < 0 or rank >= filter_size:
    raise RuntimeError('rank not within filter footprint size')
if rank == 0:
    return minimum_filter(input, None, footprint, output, mode, cval,
                          origins)
elif rank == filter_size - 1:
    return maximum_filter(input, None, footprint, output, mode, cval,
                          origins)
```

Additionally, earlier in that function `rank=size//2`.

In this case, the program is performing a minimum filter, and not a true median filter (which would involve averaging).

Both the conditions `rank==0` and `rank==size-1` are true, but control flow prioritizes `rank==0`, which corresponds to the minimum filter in the code.

Sizes >=4 may work differently.

Comment: How does `rank=size//2` lead to `rank==0`? That only happens if `size` is 0 or 1, not if it’s larger as in this case.